# Avoid variable recomputation?

Tags: python, optimization, dynamic-programming, memoization

I have a line code like this -

```
while someMethod(n) < length and List[someMethod(n)] == 0:
    # do something
    n += 1
```

where `someMethod(arg)` does some computation on the number `n`. The problem with this code is that I'm doing the same computation twice, which is something I need to avoid.

One option is to do this -

```
x = someMethod(n)
while x < length and List[x] == 0:
    # do something
    x = someMethod(n + 1)
```

I am storing the value of `someMethod(n)` in a variable `x` and then using it later. However, the problem with this approach is that the code is inside a recursive method which is called multiple times. As a result, a lot of excess instances of variables `x` are being created which slows the code down.

Here's the snipped of the code -

```
def recursion(x, n, i):
    while someMethod(n) < length and List[someMethod(n)] == 0:
        # do something
        n += 1
    # some condition
    recursion(x - 1, n, someList(i + 1))
```

and this recursion method is called many times throughout the code and the recursion is quite deep.
Is there some alternative available to deal with a problem like this?

Please try to be language independent if possible.

Comment: An int on the stack doesn't slow anything down, not in Java, not in C, not in C++, not in FORTRAN, not in Pascal, not in ALGOL 60, not in...

Comment: It's hard to understand this without a *complete* example... in particular, the claim that "excess instances of variables `x` are being created which slows the code down" really requires a bit more justification...

Comment: Ok. I'll edit the question.

Comment: I have edited the question. It's still quite hard to justify my code because it quite complex. Hope the new edit help.

Comment: If you want a language independent answer why did you tag it with python? (if someone else added that tag, perhaps you should roll back that edit).

Comment: I was unsure about it. I added it before at the current time, I'm working with Python.

Comment: It kind of pains me to see how close this is to being a good question, but a couple of the things other people have mentioned hold it back. Specifically, for one thing, this is not the type of problem where you can get a meaningful language-agnostic solution. If you're using Python, just make it about Python. And also, your claim about excess variables slowing the code down is kind of unbelievable. If that's really the case, we'll need to see some evidence - either timing results with and without the variables, or better yet, a small _complete_ program that we can run to reproduce the effect.

Comment: Note also that your code as written appears to be a classic tail-recursive thing... meaning in some languages, the compiler will basically not require a stack to store stuff, and that also you should be able to rewrite it manually to be a purely iterative code for languages that don't (python being in the latter for at least cpython) ... your claims seem to indicate that this isn't the case, and so you should probably improve your example to show why this isn't the case

Answer (score 1):

You can use memoization with decorators technique:

```
def memoize(f):
    memo = dict()
    def wrapper(x):
        if x not in memo:
            memo[x] = f(x)
        return memo[x]
    return wrapper

@memoize
def someMethod(x):
    return <your computations with x>
```

Comment: OP says that "please be language agnostic"

Comment: Firstly, thanks for the answer. Memoization like this is not really useful for me because the code is called so many times that the memoization itself slows the code down.

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry the OP's request in this regard is not appropriate for SO - then he should have asked it on programmers or cs - SO is about concrete programming problems

Answer (score 0):

As i understand your code correctly you are looking for some sort of memorization.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization

it means that on every recursive call you have to save as mush as possible past calculations to use it in current calculation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried using memoization but with no luck. The code is called so many times that memoization itself slows down the code.

Comment: @ArulxZ i did't see any form of memorization in your code

Comment: I mean I tried it but I removed it later because it wasn't really useful. The results for `someMethod(n)` and `someMethod(m)` are almost never same.

Comment: @ArulxZ memoization isn't a panacea which magically converts bad recursive algorithms into good recursive algorithms. It *can* lead to dramatic improvements -- but can also lead to degradation due to overhead. If it doesn't help you then it doesn't help you, though in that case it seems odd that you asked about it. If you have a subcase of input for which it would be helpful, perhaps you could create a memoized helper function to handle the subcase.